# Bottle Conditioned Infographic

Tags: bottle-conditioning

I have a few brews that a friend wants to try, and in the interest of safety, it's probably best I send them home with the brews rather than letting them drive home afterwards. I'd like to send the brews with instructions on how to chill, wait for settling, and how to pour.

However, while I could write up a simple text version, it would be neat if I could print out an infographic to send with the six pack. Does anyone have a fun, 8.5x11 (or smaller) infographic on how to enjoy a homebrew/bottle conditioned beer?

I'd make one myself, but I'm quite graphic design challenged.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google on 'how to pour homebrew' returns a few results. This one is pretty good:

[image]

(source: http://www.whatwouldjesusbrew.co.uk/pouring-instructions-for-homebrew-beer-labels/)

Other formatting options from what seems to be the same person:

- http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f14/homebrew-pouring-instructions-337652/
- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByU44-AmLRqXblpaXzQ3Rk1xeHM/edit

And of course there are some instructions in [How to Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11-9.html), though the graphic is not as nice.